# How to create random float number (between a range) for param_grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random

I want to create float numbers between (0.2, 0.3) inside `param_grid`. I have the code

```
    test_size = (0.2, 0.3)
    param_iters = 2
    param_grid = {
        "test_size": uniform(test_size[0], test_size[1]),
    }
    sampler = list(ParameterSampler(param_grid, n_iter=param_iters))
    args = [Namespace(**{**args, **dict(params=params)}) for params in sampler]
```

But I have found that the train_size are  `0.3897422919229748` and `0.4852142919229748`. That means I am getting over the range (0.2, 0.3)

I also tried to use the below code

```
    param_grid = {
        "test_size": round(random.uniform(test_size[0], test_size[1]), 2),
    }
```

But getting an error at the next line

`Parameter value is not iterable or distribution (key='test_size', value=0.24)`

How can I limit the train_size in between (0.2, 0.3) inside `param_grid`?

Comment: Why the `numpy` tag?

Comment: @hpaulj I used `numpy` as we can create a random number using `numpy`

Comment: @hpaulj no, this `rand(random.uniform), 2)` for `stats`. However, I tried, `np.random.uniform(test_size[0], test_size[1])` and I was getting the same error `Parameter value is not iterable or distribution`

Comment: You need to make the imports and tags clear.  Otherwise we'll (or at least I) will assume `uniform` is from `np.random` or the python `random`.  Either case it produces one random number.  Overall your code is not reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @mb4329, I would like to change a little. Here instead of `1` you have to use `param_iters`. Otherwise, you will get only `1` test_size.

```
    param_grid = {
        "test_size": np.random.uniform(test_size[0], test_size[1], param_iters)
    }
```

Output

```
{'test_size': array([0.23745401, 0.29507143])}
[{'test_size': 0.23745401188473625}, {'test_size': 0.2950714306409916}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to return a list instead of float in that second example

```
test_size = (0.2, 0.3)
x = np.random.uniform(test_size[0], test_size[1], 1)
print(x)
>> [0.2100939]
```

Comment: Nope, they are not random. Just equally spaced!

Comment: Thanks, I already tried. As I am using inside `sampler` I was getting `Parameter value is not iterable or distribution (key='test_size', value=0.24)`

Comment: Ah well it looks like it is looking for an iterable, ie [0.21] instead of 0.21, specifying the random function to return a list instead of float may work